# Build problems with ActionBarSherlock 4.2

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, compiler-errors, actionbarsherlock

I have an Android project I'm developing using ABS 4.2 - the development box is running Mint 12 32bit with jdk 1.7.0_03 installed, using Eclipse Indigo.

I recently updated my laptop and installed Mint 13 64bit, jdk 1.7.0_07 and Eclipse Juno.

I pulled the workspace across from the desktop (via SVN) and have wasted about two days trying to build ABS (not even my own project yet!) to no avail.  I keep getting a heap of errors (always 85), starting with a load of...

```
Cannot cast from Activity to SherlockFragmentActivity   SherlockDialogFragment.java /library/src/com/actionbarsherlock/app  line 27 Java Problem
```

I've checked the java and javac settings on both boxes - they both resolve to the Oracle installed software.

I've checked the project properties, both machines target 4.0.3 API 15 and the compiler compliance levels are both 1.6 - I'm really at a loss what else could be wrong, it all works fine on the desktop, just not on the laptop.

Could anyone please suggest what else I can try to resolve this?  I really have run out of ideas.

Comment: perhaps a compatibility library version difference? have you installed the compatibility library on the new project?

Comment: First, are there any errors/warnings about classpath issues? Those would be the ones to start with. (Check that you have the same Android platforms and support libs installed on both) Next, have you tried it with Indigo on your laptop? Juno is a major eclipse re-write and many plugins don't work well on it. I know the Eclipse Android tools (ADT) were flaky on there for a while...

Comment: @Steelight - I believe the compatibility library is correctly installed, it comes in the Sherlock project and is available on both machines.

Comment: @Scott Stanchfield - I hadn't thought of Juno being the issue, an interesting thought - I'll give that a go and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it would appear that SVN doesn't carry *everything* across from one machine to the other, though I still have to identify what wasn't (and include it so I have a full valid code base in SVN!).

I tried Indigo and it made no difference, exactly the same result, I also double-checked the libraries and they all seemed good.  So I then decided to copy across everything I could, direct from one machine to the other, rather than using SVN (though didn't copy the sdks).  Lo and behold... it worked!

I've preserved all the previous directories that I've now copied so will run a diff and see if I can identify what is different in either the workspace or elsewhere.  I'll let you know if I manage to identify the culprit.

Many thanks for both your suggestions, between them they were enough to redirect my thoughts to a slightly different approach, which paid off.

Convivial Latest Arbitrary Chronometric Measurement Period to you both.

Comment: Did you ever identify what the differences were?

Comment: Sadly no, it must be something which doesn't appear related or in the workspace.  At one point I checked in pretty much every file I could think of in that space and it didn't resolve it so I now simply take a weekly zip  of the workspace on each machine and restore it when necessary before restoring from SVN.  That said, I haven't had the issue of late and I'm now on Kepler so perhaps Scott's Juno suggestion was correct.